# Proof that $ f: X \times \mathbb{R} \to X: (x,\lambda) \mapsto \lambda x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space, and $\|\cdot\|_M : X \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+: (x,y) \mapsto \max(\|x\|,|y|)$.

> Proof that $ f: X \times \mathbb{R} \to X: (x,\lambda) \mapsto \lambda x$ is continuous by using the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ defintion of continuity.

This is what I've got so far:

Take $(a,b) \in X \times \mathbb{R}$, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$, $\forall (x,y) \in X \times \mathbb{R}$:

$\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|_M=||(x-a,y-b)\|_M=\max(\|x-a\|,|y-b|)<\delta$

$\|f(x,y)-f(a,b)\|=\|yx-ab\|=\|y(x-a)+a(y-b)\| \le |y|\|x-a\| + \|a\||y-b|$

I don't know what to do now, because I don't have any information about $|y|$ and $\|a\|$...

Comment: Your "epsilon" will depend on the size of $a$ and $y$; your function is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I thought epsilon only could depend on delta?

Comment: You're trying to show that $f$ is continuous at each point. So you hold that point fixed, then choose $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ accordingly. Your choices will depend on the point that you're at, but it's okay as long as the choice is possible.

Comment: So it's okay to pick $\epsilon=\delta (|y|+||a||)$

Comment: So I guess I misread your question a little bit, it should depend on $a,b$, not $a,y$.

Comment: then I'm still stuck with the $|y|$

Comment: $y$ is at most a distance $\delta$ from $b$, so $|y|$ can be estimated in terms of $|b|$ and $\delta$.

Comment: is it wrong to say $\epsilon= \delta (\delta + |b| + ||a||)$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily, though remember that ultimately the continuity condition is of the form "For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$..., so you need to show that $\delta$ can be chosen given $\epsilon$, which you might be able to do by inverting the expression.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't isolate $\delta$ in the equation

Comment: I will post an answer then, but for reference it is important that you only need to show that there exists a $\delta$; there need not be an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already shown, we can bound
$$
|\lambda x - \alpha y| < |\lambda| \delta + |y| \delta < |\lambda| \delta + (\delta + |x|) \delta < 2M \delta + \delta^2
$$
where $M = \max(|x|, |\lambda|)$. Now choose $\delta < M$. Then 
$$
|\lambda x - \alpha y| < 3M \delta,
$$
in which case we can guarantee that $|f(x,\lambda) - f(y, \alpha)| < \epsilon$ by choosing any $\delta$ satisfying $\delta < \epsilon /(3M)$ and $\delta < M$.